# Is there a way to apply a git commit to a list of branches?

Tags: git

Basically, what I'm looking for is a cherry-pick that can take multiple destination branches.

Occasionally there's a commit that's immediately useful to all collaborators on a project, such as new documentation, an update to an external dependency or an additional script or tool that makes life easier.

Is there a git command that will apply the a given commit to a list of branches? E.g., something like a `git mass-cherry-pick 1c23f6b7 -- some-branch another-branch a-third-branch`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would want to do it this way, rather than just pushing that commit to a main branch that the collaborators can pull from?

Comment: Think of the complications of resolving possible and *different* merge conflicts across the branches. Better go individually.

Comment: Sounds something you could script so that you can add it so you run `git mass-cherry-pick blahblah`. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: Thanks, @eftshift0. I'll probably do that if there's nothing built-in.

Comment: @scatter the specific reason is efficacy. Why collectively go through 10+ cherry-picks instead of 1?

Comment: @EugeneSh., I'm not a fan of this kind of reflexive dismissal based on potential scenarios where a tool isn't the best option. There have been no merge conflicts in any of the last several times I've done this manually. Even if there were conflicts, a git mass-cherry-pick command would almost certainly have an --abort flag, which would then allow the user to go through each cherry-pick separately.